# Passive Rigid Body Abnormal hitbox

Tags: animation, mesh, vertices, timeline, cell-fracture

Okay, basically I tried to make a shattering block fall but everytime I run it, theres always a gap:
[image]

Ive never had this happen, any ideas?

FILE: https://www.mediafire.com/file/m8lcjdjd65natdl/brickanim.blend/file

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale of your floor, delete the bake and bake again.